# Plot seaborn plot for only few columns in 'col' parameters

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm looking to plot per year the distribution of sunshine depending on the season with seaborn.

```
sns.displot(x = 'Sunshine', data = dviz, kind ='kde', hue = 'season', col = 'year')
```

Here is the dataset :
[image]

And the displot returned are :

[image]

Columns 'year' contains year from 2009 to 2020 and I want to plot only for last 5 years ( 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020).

This is corresponding to the last five plot

Do yo know how to select the values that I want for the col?

Thank you !

Comment: It seems your question has nothing to do with seaplot or plots in general. It has to do with data engineering and being able to filter a dataset based on a particular condition.

Comment: It is always good to put some sample of your data to ease the support

Comment: @karlphillip I don't understand why you are telling this, I think the issue could be resolved by a good use of seaborn distplot or Facetgrid

Comment: @Ahribba Alex answer is correct and proves the point I made earlier. The reason I mentioned the obviousness of the problem (though it didn't made sense to you at first), is that a good question title with a solid description of the issue, along with a reproducible example, has a much higher probability to get people to answer your question! Otherwise, it can become quite a long cat & mouse game on the comment section for us to understand what the issue is all about. That's also why many people don't bother answering questions from new users. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply filter the data as [Crocs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335090/crocs) mentioned:

```
dviz_selected = dviz.loc[(dviz["year"] >= 2016) & (dviz["year"] <= 2020)]

sns.displot(x = 'Sunshine', data = dviz_selected, kind ='kde', hue = 'season', col = 'year')
```

Comment: It works well. Thank you. 
Thanks to @Crocs also :)